# How to edit the SASS variable headerSeperatorColor in CSS file?

Tags: css, tabulator

I am currently customising the styling of a [tabulator table](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/style) and wish to edit the headerSeperatorColor variable.

I can edit the standard CSS variables easily.

For example, I have changed the background colour of the odd and even rows as follows:

```
.tabulator .tabulator-row-odd {
    background-color: black;
}

.tabulator .tabulator-row-even {
    background-color: white;
}
```

However, I also need to edit one of the SASS variables called `headerSeperatorColor`.

Can this be achieved in the same CSS file? If not, how do you edit the variable?

I am using version 4.4.3

Comment: It instructs how to do so right in the [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/style#sass-default)

Comment: I tried adding `$headerSeperatorColor:black;` to the CSS file, but it did nothing

Comment: `$headerSeperatorColor:black;` is not css but a sass variable from the config file / sass files. this is where you need to update it.

Comment: CSS is not SCSS, it has no way to parse that as a variable without sass as the processor of it.

Comment: I see. I couldn't edit the sass file. however, I took the original sass file and converted it to a css file and found the element I needed to change. It was `.tabulator .tabulator-header` editing the value `border-bottom:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header {
    border-bottom: GREEN;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some explanation as though why this answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator SASS variables are set as [Default Variables](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/sass-default) which means if you want to recompile the SASS you can simply set the ***$headerSeperatorColor*** variable before you import the scss file and it will override the variable:

```
$headerSeperatorColor: #FF0000;
@import "tabulator.scss";
```